# Procedure to delete my own site on area51

Tags: support, area-51

I want to delete the site proposed by me. How can I do that?
I hit the delete button below the sitename but it will vote for deleting the site. As its my own site I should be able to delete directly.
my site is ['Database Design'](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11936/database-design)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because deletion is a voting action; if it's done by the community, it will require 5(?) votes; however, a vote by the owner or the moderators is taken as a master vote.

<s>Once you propose a site to Area 51, it's not owned by you anymore. The proposal belongs to the Area 51 community, and thusly, the community must agree to delete the proposal before it can be deleted.</s>

Comment: and how many votes the site need to be deleted?

Comment: Hey, I just hit the delete button then navigate away from the site, then again try to find the site but I didn't see that site anywhere. The name was 'Database Design'

Comment: @Himadri I've revised my answer to reflect your experience. Sorry, I didn't actually test the behavior myself.

Comment: OK...So, finally I got my site deleted.Can you tell me where this rules are written?